# SwiftUI, Using textContentType on textfield causes lag running 14.4.1

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am seeing this issue in my main app, so I put together a simple little app here with one textfield.  Setting the `.textContentType` on the TextField will cause the app the stutter and lag when typing in relatively fast on the keyboard.  Using `.emailAdress` seems like the worst, as `.givenName` was a bit better but still lag was noticeable.  Adding or removing the `.keyboardType` had no effect on my issue.  I am testing with a physical iPhone 12 running 14.4.1.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var text = ""
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.red
            VStack {
                TextField("TextField", text: $text)
                    .textContentType(.emailAddress) //comment this out and lag is gone
                    .background(Color.green)
            }
        }
        .onTapGesture {
            self.hideKeyboard()
        }
    }
}

extension View {
    func hideKeyboard() {
        UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), 
                                        to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: tried your code, works very well for me, no lag at all.

Tested with and without, the following: `.onTapGesture` and `.disableAutocorrection(true)`

Try removing `.onTapGesture` to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: @workingdog, Tried both suggestions and see no difference.  I made the project in UIKit and the see the same problem.  Can you let me know the device and iOS version you are using?

Comment: ha yes sorry, I'm on macos 12.beta, xcode 13.beta, targets ios 15 and macCatalyst 12. 
Tested on macOS 12 and iPhone 10 ios 15 and older iPad 14.7.1. I forgot that you are on an older ios.

Answer (score 0):

So, I upgraded my iOS to OS to 14.7.1 as @workingdog was using and it seemed to fix my problem.  As I said previously, I was using 14.4.1 and it must have been an OS issue.  Problem is resolved on os update.  Thanks!